# Настройка домена, добавление записей типа А, VPS сервер

Tags: сервер, vps, домен, vds, поддомены

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно добавлять и какие записи должны быть в настройке домена типа А. То есть у меня уже есть 3 записи типа А, очевидно которые ссылаются на ИП сервера, но они у меня были уже по умолчанию, где просто домен, *.доменное имя и www.доменное имя, что нужно еще добавить?

Comment: Записи должны быть такие, какие вам нужны. Если вы не знаете, что вам ещё нужно, то видимо и добавлять записи больше не нужно

Comment: Так не в этом суть, как понять что конкретно нужно то?

Comment: Если вы не знаете, что вам нужно — значит ничего